# Jquery UI box - Takes more than 1 click to run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically appending a `<div>` to the body of my webpage. This `<div>` does not exist on my .html page.
 Within this `<div>` I am creating a Jquery UI YES NO box. Quite simply, it will 'do something' and close the box when YES, and just close the box when NO.
I have a working piece of code to create this box. However, frequently it takes two clicks of the YES button to work, which is very confusing. You'll see I have used a variety of methods to close the box.

```
                $(function () {
                    $('body').append('<div id="dialog-confirm"></div>').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    });

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        modal: true,
         title: 'Choose item?',
        buttons: 
        {
             'YES': function () {
                 $(this).dialog("close");
                //$("#dialog-confirm").dialog("close");
                //$('body').remove('#dialog-confirm');
                $('#dialog-confirm').remove();
            },
                'NO': function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                //$("#dialog-confirm").dialog("close");
                //$('body').remove('#dialog-confirm');
                $('#dialog-confirm').remove();
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is a race condition between your adding the div and attaching the click handler.  Sometimes it happens before, sometimes after.  That's why you get inconsistent click behavior.  Try the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').append('<div id="dialog-confirm"></div>');
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen : true,
        height : 200,
        width : 200,
        modal : true,
        title : 'Choose item?',
        buttons : {
            'YES' : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                // $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("close");
                // $('body').remove('#dialog-confirm');
                $('#dialog-confirm').remove();
            },
            'NO' : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                // $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("close");
                // $('body').remove('#dialog-confirm');
                $('#dialog-confirm').remove();
            }
        }
    });
    $('#dialog-confirm').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    });
});
```